# Error when training CNN: "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1"

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new to Pytorch and I'm trying to implemente a simple CNN to recognize MNIST images.

I'm training the network using MSE Loss as loss function and SGD as optimizer. When I get to the training it gives me the following

> warning: " UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([64])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 10])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size."

And then I get the following

```
error: "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b
       (64) at non-singleton dimension 1".
```

I've tried to solve it using some solutions I've found in other questions but nothing seems to work. Here's the code of how I load the dataset:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,),(0.5,))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train = True, transform = transform, download = True)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size = 64, shuffle = True)

testset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train = False, transform = transform, download = True)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size = 64, shuffle = False)
```

The code to define my network:

```
    class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        #Convolutional layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 12, 5)
        #Fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(12*4*4, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 60)
        self.out = nn.Linear(60,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2,2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2,2))
        x = x.reshape(-1, 12*4*4)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))         
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.out(x)
        return x
```

And this is the training:

```
net = Net()
print(net)

criterion = nn.MSELoss() 
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
epochs = 3

for epoch in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0;
    for images, labels in trainloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = net(images)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
    else:
        print(f"Training loss: {running_loss/len(trainloader)}")

print('Finished training')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loss you're using (`nn.MSELoss`) is incorrect for this problem. You should use `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`.

**Mean Squared Loss measures the mean squared error between input x and target y.** Here the input and target naturally should be of the same shape.

**Cross Entropy Loss computes the probability over the classes for each image.** The output would be a matrix N x C and target would be a vector of size N. (N = batch size, C = number of classes)

Since your aim is to classify the image, this is what you'll want to use.

In your case, your network output will be a matrix of size 64 x 10 and target is a vector of size 64. Each row of the output matrix (after applying the softmax function) indicates the probability of that class after which the Cross entropy loss is computed. Pytorch's `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` combines both the softmax operation with the loss computation.

You can refer the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) for more info on how Pytorch computes losses.

Comment: What should be used to have any other loss except CrossEntropyLoss? I was trying to use L2 loss, but I had the same problem. Argmax also is not working in the backward pass.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AshwinNair advise and I did change in for loop in train and eval section as below it work for me.

`for i, (img, label) in enumerate(dataloader):`

```
  img = img.to(device)

  label = label.to(device)`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).